# Which NoSQL for storing images as 2D arrays (BLOBs)

Tags: mongodb, nosql, cassandra

I have large number of images that I need to access on per-pixel-basis in my app. The images are downloaded from web and are quite large (4k). Update is done several times a day (tousands of images), reading is non-stop.

Currently I use PostGis and store images tiled in raster column type. However, performance is not the best, mainly updates are quite slow (transaction, index update etc).

So I would like to use NoSQL database, since I really dont need SQL.

***My workflow is:***

**Insertion** - download image -> split it to tiles of size 64x64 (compress them if necessary with arithetic or huffman coder) -> store tiles in database

**Selection** - read pixel [x, y] -> locate tile -> retrieve tile -> "unpack" tile in memory -> locate pixel [x, y] -> return value to user

What database should I use for this purpose? I have looked to MongoDB and Cassandra. The later one seems more appropriate for this task.

Comment: Theoretically (I didn't use it for that use case) Cassandra will work for you - the 4k image should be ~23-25Mb in total, if you split it into tiles, then it's manageable. You can use picture ID as a partition key, and then form the clustering key from the tile ID - depending on your requirements, like, do you need to think how you'll access data, like, if you need to pull multiple tiles together...

Comment: don't save images in databases, save the file and link only the path

Comment: @nbk With this I would have to open images (or the tiles) manually. I expect that DB system have some cache or something to speed it up for repeated reads of the same image (tile). Another way, I would have to manage file system, where tousand or millions of small images (=tiles) exist. I would end up with problems of too many files in directory (max number depends on the filesystem) or some path logic to keep it cleaned. Scalability is another problem. Database system should solve this by its own.

Comment: i doubt that modern filesystems can't handle billions of files, ssds are very fast, so i see npt a porblem. but the discusuuin is ld see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278186/storing-images-in-nosql-stores